# How to sync v-model to customize Vue component with wrapper?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am newbie in VueJs.
I want to create customize component with wrapper like this:

```
template: `<div class="wrapper">
            <input name="name" /> 
          </div>`,
```

when using component, I want to add v-model,

```
 <my-component v-model="form.input" />
```

But in actually, the value of model is bind just to the wrapper not to the input. If I change the model

> form:{ input: "edited" }

that value only bind to wrapper like:

```
  <div class="wrapper" value="edited">
        <input name="name" /> 
   </div>
```

is there any suggestion for my problem. 
I am using Vuejs-2.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Binding-Native-Events-to-Components

Answer (score 0):

At minimum, you would need to do something like this:

```vue
<div class="wrapper">
  <input
    :value="value"
    @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
  /> 
</div>
```

```js
props: ['value']
```